# “Substantial drift from” in celery

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have 4 servers. One of them is in Germany and the others are in one other country. I have run celery with Redis backend on all of these 4 VMs. when I stop my code to run on the server in Germany, all the things are good But when I add the Germany server to the cycle and run my codes on it, I get `Substantial drift from` message on it and get too many `missed heartbeat` on the other servers. I first see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745486/celery-substantial-drift-from) question and then checked the time zone. They were not the same. So I change and make all 4 servers the same time zone using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal) post. Nothing happened and the problem still existed. Then I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049404/celery-workers-missing-heartbeats-and-getting-substantial-drift-over-ec2) but again Nothing happened. This is my celery config:

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

and when I check `utcoffset` using a shell in python, I get `-4` for all of the servers. How can I fix this issue to run fine my codes on all 4 servers?

**EDITED**

I also do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049404/celery-workers-missing-heartbeats-and-getting-substantial-drift-over-ec2) and set the `BROKER_HEARTBEAT` to zero. But no changes.